# WebView ends up in infinite loop when going back if it follows an alternative link

Tags: android, android-webview

Take for example the url https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/51519206 . In the response body it sends back `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/51519206" />` which will in many cases lead a browser and - in my case - a `WebView` to follow the alternative link and load that page. That's all good.

The challenge is when the user wants to go back. In a browser you will see that clicking back will not take you back to the `co.uk` address that the redirect came from. And that is the behaviour I would have expected from `WebView`. However, `WebView`'s `canGoBack()` will return `true` and `goBack()` will make the `WebView` load the `co.uk` address and then again follow the redirect. So the user is stuck if not clicking back twice very quickly.

**Is there a way around this behaviour?** Is there for example a way to do one of the following options?

- Set some setting so that `goBack()` work as the user would expect.
- Know that URL loaded was caused by a redirect and that `goBack()` should be called twice/X times? (The `WebResourceRequest` returns `false` for `isRedirect()` (as expected as that is for server side redirects).)
- Tell the `WebView` not to follow alternative links

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, `window.history.back()` in javascript instead of the webview's `goBack()` will work as you expect. So `mWebView.evaluateJavascript("window.history.back();");`.

Behind the scenes, the WebView is just Chromium, so it's weird that the goBack behavior is different.

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to be working for me. Urls: http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/51773294 --> https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/51773294 , WebView: com.google.android.webview version 80.0.3987.132, Android 10